# shopping cart issues while adding color option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, shopping-cart, cart

please check this [demo](http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-shopping-cart-demo/). here one product with different color is not added into the cart but its updated the same product with different color which is not the right way.

here is code to **add the product**.

```
    if(isset($_POST["product_code"]) && isset($_POST["product_color"]))
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //create a new product array 
    }

    //we need to get product name and price from database.
    $statement = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products_list WHERE product_code=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $product_price);


    while($statement->fetch()){ 
        $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name; //fetch product name from database
        $new_product["product_price"] = $product_price;  //fetch product price from database
        $new_product["product_color"] = $_POST["product_color"];

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){  //if session var already exist
        $check = $_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']][$new_product['product_color']];
            if(isset($check)) //check item exist in products array
            {
                unset($check); //unset old item
            }           
        }

        $check = $new_product;  //update products with new item array   
    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]); //count total items
    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items))); //output json 

}
```

In above code how should I add the color of product also so that the one product with different color can be added?

**list the items in cart code**

```
 if(isset($_POST["load_cart"]) && $_POST["load_cart"]==1)
    {

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){ //if we have session variable
            $cart_box = '<ul class="cart-products-loaded">';
            $total = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //loop though items and prepare html content

                //set variables to use them in HTML content below
                $product_name = $product["product_name"]; 
                $product_price = $product["product_price"];
                $product_code = $product["product_code"];
                $product_qty = $product["product_qty"];
                $product_color = $product["product_color"];
                //$product_size = $product["product_size"];

                //$cart_box .=  "<li> $product_name (Qty : $product_qty | $product_color  | $product_size ) &mdash; $currency ".sprintf("%01.2f", ($product_price * $product_qty)). " <a href=\"#\" class=\"remove-item\" data-code=\"$product_code\">&times;</a></li>";

                $cart_box .=  "<li> $product_name (Qty : $product_qty | $product_color ) &mdash; $currency ".sprintf("%01.2f", ($product_price * $product_qty)). " <a href=\"#\" class=\"remove-item\" data-code=\"$product_code\">&times;</a></li>";

                $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
                $total = ($total + $subtotal);
            }
            $cart_box .= "</ul>";
            $cart_box .= '<div class="cart-products-total">Total : '.$currency.sprintf("%01.2f",$total).' <u><a href="view_cart.php" title="Review Cart and Check-Out">Check-out</a></u></div>';
            die($cart_box); //exit and output content
        }else{
            die("Your Cart is empty"); //we have empty cart
        }
    }
```

**Remove item from cart**

```
if(isset($_GET["remove_code"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_GET["remove_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get the product code to remove

    if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]))
    {
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]);
    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items)));
}
```

In above code also how the color of product should be compared? e.g. Cool T-shirt | Blue and Cool T-shirt | Red and if Cool T-shirt | Red is removed then both should not be removed.

Can anyone please help me in this?